# generate all combinations to extend to large columns

Tags: matlab, combinations, element

I have C columns where I want to fill all combinations of N elements (C>N). How can I do it in Matlab?
Example: C= 5, N=3; then all the combinations of N from 1 to N i.e. 1 to 3 to be filled in C=5 columns. I tried NchooseK but could not achieve this. The expected output looks as below:

Output: 11111,
        11112,
        11122,
        11222,
       .....,
        22222,
        22223,
        22233,
       .....,
        33333,
        .....
        12312,
        12313,
        12323,
       ...so on ...
In this way all combinations of 1 to N filled upto C columns. My C can be as large as 40, and N can be 10.
Is there any way in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tree traversal problem. Here is a DFS method:

```
function s = GetCombinations(C,N)
C = int64(C);
N = int64(N);
assert(C>0 && N>0, 'Invalid input')
s = prtstr(C,N,''); % wrap the iterative function
end

function s = prtstr(C,N,prefix)
s = cell(N^C,1);
if C == 1
    for ii = 1:N
        s{ii} = [prefix, num2str(ii)];
    end
else
    BlockLen = N^(C-1);
    for ii = 1:N
        s((1+(ii-1)*BlockLen) : (ii*BlockLen)) = ....
            prtstr(C-1,N,[prefix, num2str(ii)]);
    end
end
end
```

Output is a cell vector containing all combination strings.

```
>> s = GetCombinations(5,3)

s = 

    '11111'
    '11112'
    '11113'
    '11121'
    '11122'
    '11123'
    '11131'
    '11132'
    '11133'
    '11211'
    '11212'
    '11213'
    '11221'
    '11222'
    '11223'
    '11231'
    '11232'
    ....
```

---

Edit: Skip duplicate cases. For example, `11112` and `11121` are considered the same and only the first one is listed.

```
function s = GetCombinations(C,N)
C = int64(C);
N = int64(N);
assert(C>0 && N>0, 'Invalid input')
s = prtstr(C,N,'',1);
s = s(~cellfun(@isempty,s));
end

function s = prtstr(C,N,prefix,startN)
s = cell(N^C,1);
if C == 1
    for ii = startN:N
        s{ii} = [prefix, num2str(ii)];
    end
else
    BlockLen = N^(C-1);
    for ii = startN:N
        s((1+(ii-1)*BlockLen) : (ii*BlockLen)) = ....
            prtstr(C-1,N,[prefix, num2str(ii)], ii);
    end
end
end

>> s = GetCombinations(5, 3)

s = 

    '11111'
    '11112'
    '11113'
    '11122'
    '11123'
    '11133'
    '11222'
    '11223'
    '11233'
    '11333'
    '12222'
    '12223'
    '12233'
    '12333'
    '13333'
    '22222'
    '22223'
    '22233'
    '22333'
    '23333'
    '33333'
```

---

Edit: For large `C` and `N`, pre-allocating the cell array is not feasible. In fact most of the cells are empty. Which ones are empty can be pre-determined, but this itself is an interesting problem. Yet I just append the cell array on the go instead of pre-allocating it. So a bit slower but it works.

```
function s = GetCombinations(C,N)
C = int64(C);
N = int64(N);
assert(C>0 && N>0, 'Invalid input')
s = prtstr(C,N,'',1);
s = s(~cellfun(@isempty,s));
end

function s = prtstr(C,N,prefix,startN)
s = cell(0,1);
if C == 1
    nt = N-startN+1;
    t = cell(nt,1);
    for ii = 1:nt
        t{ii} = [prefix, num2str(ii+startN-1)];
    end
    s = t;
else
    for ii = startN:N
         t = prtstr(C-1,N,[prefix, num2str(ii)], ii);
         s = [s;t];
    end
end
end
```

---

EDIT: Memory-less version. 
Requested `(C,N) = (20,10)` and the result is too large to be held in the memory. One possible solution is to just print out the result without storing it. Below is the code, tested.

```
function GetCombinations(C,N, fh)
C = int64(C);
N = int64(N);
assert(C>0 && N>0, 'Invalid input')
prtstr(C,N,'',1, fh);
end

function prtstr(C,N,prefix,startN, fh)
if isempty(fh) % assign fh = [] if you do not want text file output
    fh = 1; % print to command window
end
if C == 1
    for ii = 1:N-startN+1
        fprintf(fh, '%s%d\n', prefix, ii+startN-1);
    end
else
    for ii = startN:N
        prtstr(C-1,N,[prefix, num2str(ii)], ii, fh)
    end
end
end
```

The function takes an additional input argument `fh` which is a file handle. Because `(20,10)` has quite a lot of lines of output (10m+ lines and 200MB+), you might want to print the result directly into a text file. To achieve this,

```
fh = fopen('testout.txt','w');
GetCombinations(20,10,fh)
fclose(fh)
```

Otherwise, if you really want to print the result into the command window, use

```
GetCombinations(20,10,[])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But there are repeated combinations for example '11112' and '11121' which has the same digits. In such a case I need to retain only one sequence '11112' OR '11121'. any suggestions?

Comment: thank you very much. It works for small values. But my requirement as I mentioned in question large values of C, it gives error. Any help?

Comment: Have same issues with (C,N) = (20,10) or (30,8) any solutions please?

Comment: Error using vertcat
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

@ Yvon Error in GettCombinations>prtstr (line 21)
         s = [s;t];

Error in GettCombinations>prtstr (line 20)
         t = prtstr(C-1,N,[prefix, num2str(ii)], ii);

Comment: @ Yvon is it possible to have C=40 and N=10 without memory out?

Comment: It is possible if you only need the text output printed in the command window. In that way I won't store any string in the memory.

Comment: @ Yvon yes,to print the content as we do now itself has issues with (C,N)= (20,10). I could not figure out how to deal this?

Comment: Added to answer.